# Coloring Provinces with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to color provinces using the map styling features of Google maps. I've defined a style but it doesn't seem to work. If I change **geometry.fill** to just **geometry**, I get the color on the province borders, so the style seems to be wired properly to the map, but I can't get the fill to work/

```
          var styleProv = [
            {
                featureType: 'administrative.province',
                elementType: 'geometry.fill',   //this doesn't seem to work
                stylers: [
                    { hue: '#eff00' },
                    { saturation: 200 },
                    { lightness: 5 },
                    { visibility: 'on' }
                ]
            }
            ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with your custom style:

- your hue hexadecimal code has 5 characters
- saturation is over 100

Besides, it turns out that only province strokes can be shown. For example, after hiding all map elements and giving province geometries colors with the [Google Maps Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/), only dashed province contours are shown.

Custom style only showing provinces (JSON format):

```
[
  {
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.province",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I've figured why: province fills are always invisible, I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: Oh well, too bad. I'm achieving the province coloring with custom polygon shapes, but it's quite a hassle. Thanks anyway.